# How not to update the user session in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project which has a routine that runs in the background, with `POST` calls via Ajax. This process runs every  minute.

My problem is: the Ajax calls are updating the active user section, always leaving the user authenticated in the system, although the session should expire in 30 minutes.

I need the Ajax call not to update the user's authentication time, losing authentication in 30 minutes in the project

My action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult ListarNotificacao()
{
    long idUsuario = Convert.ToInt64(User.Identity.GetIdUsuario());

    var qtdeNotificacao = _roboProcessoExecucaoNegocio.ListarNotificacao(idUsuario);
    var resultado = Json(new { sucesso = true, qtdeNotificacao }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return resultado;
}
```

I tried using this and it didn't work.

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```